# Calling IBM Watson's update_intent function from Python gives "Invalid Request Body"

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I have a dictionary in python of this format :

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "ER111-Test1",
      "created": "2017-08-18T18:09:36.155Z",
      "updated": "2017-08-18T18:09:41.755Z",
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "name": "ER2222-Test2",
      "created": "2017-08-18T18:05:48.153Z",
      "updated": "2017-08-18T18:06:06.004Z",
      "description": null
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "refresh_url": "/v1/workspaces/9978a49e-ea89-4493-b33d-82298d3db20d/intents?version=2017-08-21"
  }
}
```

I am trying to remove the "ER111" and "ER2222" values and reupload. I am running [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#update_intent) method from IBM Watson's API.

The code is 99% working, but won't let me upload at the final step.

```
response = ...
names = [d['name'] for d in response['intents']]

for name in names:
  fixed_name = re.sub('ER\d{4,5}-', ' ', name) #this works to remove the prefix
  print(name + '  ' + fixed_name) #testing it works, it does
  response = conversation.update_intent(workspace_id='1234567',
                                        intent=str(name),
                                        new_intent=str(fixed_name)) #fails here with code 400
```

At the final line, we fail with "Error: Invalid Request Body, Code: 400". It works if I hardcode the values rather than using variables. I have tried adding quotation marks and a few other things but can't seem to get it to play nice.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: What is this API? Are you sure you're calling it correctly? Maybe you should be passing JSON data instead of a string?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#update_intent this function. It seems to work when I replace my variables with strings directly, which is what I find a little odd!! :)

Comment: Remove the `str(..)`, those are redundant.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I thought they were and have removed them...I tried a lot of troubleshooting before posting here and that was just on step haha :) Thanks for confirming that for me.

Comment: Okay, it seems like `fixed_name` has a leading space. Could that be the reason? Can you try passing `fixed_name.strip()` and seeing what happens?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That is incredible. How did you figure that out so fast? I've been looking at this for over an hour!! Thank you so much !!! :)

Comment: Hmm, let me reshape your question and write an answer... this might help others with the same problem.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a fresh pair of eyes always helps provide a new perspective, helping you find things hiding in plain sight. Happy coding.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider marking it accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like Watson doesn't like leading spaces in the data you send. For starters, take a look here -

```
fixed_name = re.sub('ER\d{4,5}-', ' ', name)
#                                  ^
```

Since `name` begins with `ER...`, this pattern is going to be replaced with a leading space. What you should've done is to replace with the empty string, `''`.

However, a better way to do this would've been to just split on the first `-` using `str.split`. Here's how -

```
>>> "ER111-Test1".split('-', 1)[-1]
'Test1'
```